# Do we have a canonical question on interval ear-training for non-singers?

Tags: discussion, canonical-q-a

I have some ideas for a post on how to practice ear training of intervals for people who have difficulty singing on pitch.

There are a large number of questions to hunt through to try to find an appropriate place to post the tips -- if such a post exists. **Do we have an existing question where such a post would be a good fit?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of a canonical post, there are two Q&A that address the general issue:

- For ear training tips for someone with great difficulty singing on pitch, but who wants to use singing in training: [How to develop a musical ear when even singing poses great difficulty?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109974/how-to-develop-a-musical-ear-when-even-singing-poses-great-difficulty)
- For ear training using means other than singing: [How can one learn to identify intervals by ear without singing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111170/how-can-one-learn-to-identify-intervals-by-ear-without-singing)